# Can Bachelor's Thesis include online forum entries as references?

Tags: citations, thesis, bachelor

I am currently writing my bachelors thesis at a german University of applied science. My topic is somewhat unusual as it focusses on the development of a tool for Minecraft-Servers.

I want to lay down the motivation of the company I'm working for and also have to give some technical details to explain why the tool I'm building makes any sense. This requires me to explain quite a bit about the technical details of the game and the problems it has.

I'm having a really hard time to find some classical papers or any scientific references related to the background of this. Most of my knowledge comes from years of experience in the field and is not something that I could track down to a single source. I cannot even remember where I learned most of the stuff I know about this, so I don't know how to properly add "proof" of my knowledge to my thesis.

Most of the information I can verify comes from forum threads like [this](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/discussion/3127670-why-isnt-java-minecraft-multithreaded) one. They are really well written and include a lot of data. However I am not sure how well it is taken if I include some "random" game forum posts as references in my Thesis. Is this too unprofessional?

Comment: This is a question for your advisor. Only they can specify what is appropriate for you to include or not. Ask them.

Comment: If you cite anything from the web, include the date you last accessed it. Things change. Things disappear. Also see the wayback machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should include these if it helped you.
It is not uncommon to see "Personal communication" as citations/references, which is even more vague. References is not only for providing original sources, but to give credit.

For example, databases and software used is sometimes also included in the references (or acknowledgements at the very least).